# Matrix inequality between a traceless matrix and identity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrix-theory

Given a traceless matrix $C\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, i.e., tr$(C)=0$, what is the relationship between tr$|\mathbb{I}+C|$ and tr$|C|$? The two matrices are of dimension $n$.

Comment: What does $|C|$ mean?

Comment: $C$ is a traceless Hermitian matrix, and $|C|$ is simply $\sqrt{C^{\dagger}C}$. Since $C$ is traceless, we know that tr$|C|$ is just the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues, which makes tr$|C|>0$. It will only be zero if $C=0$ and it is not.

Comment: ... and what is $\Bbb{F}$?

Comment: Assuming that it is $\mathbb{C}$ (C and F are close on a keyboard), we may apply triangle inequality for the nuclear norm to conclude that they differ by at most $n$.

Comment: @abx $\mathbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field, either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Is there a method to check for a stricter bound on it? Thanks.

Comment: At first, 'arbitrary field' and 'either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$' are different things. At second, it is a bad idea to denote the set of Hermitian matrices by $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. At third, for Hermitian matrix singular values are just absolute values of eigenvalues, thus we have to say something about $A=\sum |c_i|$ and $B=\sum |1+c_i|$, where $c_i$ are eigenvalues of $C$ and $\sum c_i=0$. It is an excersise to describe the locus of possible points $(A,B)$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Is there a good textbook to read for this? I don't have a solid background in matrix theory. I just ran across this problem while doing my research in quantum information theory.

Comment: In complex case this question now looks more difficult for me than I initially thought. It is not about matrices, you just have $n$ complex numbers $c_1,\dots,c_n$ such that $\sum c_i=0$, $\sum |c_i|=A$, $\sum |1+c_i|=B$ and you have to describe a locus $(A,B)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. For example, if $n=2$, it is described by inequalities $\max(A,2)\leqslant B\leqslant \sqrt{A^2+4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $C$ is hermitian, as you say in the comments. I will also assume $n\ge2$.

### Summary

There are three cases, depending on the value of $\mathrm{tr}|C|$:

1. For $\mathrm{tr}|C|\le2(n-2)$, we have
   $$
   0\le \mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|\le n +\mathrm{tr}|C|\ .
   $$
2. For $2(n-1)\ge\mathrm{tr}|C|>2(n-2)$, there are  two possibilities: 
   $$
   4-n+\mathrm{tr}|C|\le\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|\le n  +\mathrm{tr}|C|
   $$
   or 
   $$\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|=n\ .$$
3. For $\mathrm{tr}|C|>2(n-1)$, we have
   $$
   4-n+\mathrm{tr}|C|\le\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|\le n  +\mathrm{tr}|C|\ .
   $$

---

### Derivation

We can decompose $C$ into eigenspaces with positive eigenvalues, eigenvalues in $[-1;0]$, and those below $-1$, respectively, 
$$
C=P-R-M\ ,
$$
where $P\ge0$ (positive semi-definite), $0\le R\le\mathbb{I}$, and $M\ge\mathbb{I}$, respectively, and $P$, $R$, and $M$ have orthogonal supports. Then,
$$
0=\mathrm{tr}\,C=\mathrm{tr}\,P-\mathrm{tr}\,R-\mathrm{tr}\,M\ ,
$$
and hence $\gamma:=\mathrm{tr}\,P=\mathrm{tr}\,M+\mathrm{tr}\,R$. Let us further denote $s:=\mathrm{tr}\,R$, and then $0\le\mathrm{tr}\,M=\gamma-s$, ie., there is a constraint $\gamma\ge s$.

What are the constraints on $\gamma$ and $s$?  Generally, $\gamma\ge0$ and $s\in[0;n]$. Note, however, that for $s> n-1$, $R$ must have full rank and thus $\gamma=0$. This is in contradiction to $\gamma\ge s$, ruling out $s>n-1$. Further, if $n-1\ge s> n-2$, then $\gamma\ge s>0$, and $P-R$ have rank $n$, i.e., $M=0$, and thus $\gamma=s$. It is easy to see that there are no further constraints by choosing $P$ and $M$ rank one if $s\le n-2$.

As we will now see, $\gamma$ and $s$ fully characterize both $\mathrm{tr}\,|C|$ and $\mathrm{tr}\,|\mathbb I+C|$.

First, $|C|=P+R+M$, and thus 
$$
\mathrm{tr}|C|=\gamma+s+(\gamma-s)=2\gamma\ .
$$

On the other hand, $|\mathbb I+C|=(\mathbb I+P) + (\mathbb I-R)+(M-\mathbb I)$, and thus 
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C| &= (n+\gamma) +(n-s)+((\gamma-s)-n) \\
&= n + 2\gamma-2s\\
&=(n-2s)+\mathrm{tr}|C|\ .
\end{align}

We now have to see what the possible choices for $s$ are, given $\mathrm{tr}|C|=2\gamma$. We must always have $0\le2s\le \mathrm{tr}|C|$.

1. For $\mathrm{tr}|C|\le2(n-2)$, any $0\le 2s\le\mathrm{tr}|C|$ is  admissible, giving the general constraint
   $$
   0\le \mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|\le n +\mathrm{tr}|C|\ .
   $$
2. For $2(n-1)\ge\mathrm{tr}|C|>2(n-2)$, we have two possibilities: $0\le s\le n-2$ or $2s=\mathrm{tr}|C|$. This gives the two possibilities
   $$
   4-n+\mathrm{tr}|C|\le\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|\le n  +\mathrm{tr}|C|
   $$
   or 
   $$\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|=n\ .$$
3. Finally, for $\mathrm{tr}|C|>2(n-1)$, we have that $0\le s \le n-2$, and thus only have the solution
   $$
   4-n+\mathrm{tr}|C|\le\mathrm{tr}|\mathbb I+C|\le n  +\mathrm{tr}|C|\ .
   $$